# Return action when the result is an empty array

Tags: rxjs, observable

It is possible to make this to return an action (fulfilled) when the first `mergeMap` returns an empty array?

```js
of(1)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(x => []), // this can result in empty array
      distinct(),
      mergeMap(x => {
        ...
        return fulfilled()
      })
    )
    .subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

Comment: `distinct()` will swallow any emissions that are the same.  Are you saying that if an empty array is emitted more than once you still want to return `fufilled()`?

Comment: I think you could use `multicast()` but it depends what exactly you want to do because this probably doesn't represent a real usecase.

Comment: The issue is that `mergeMap` doesn't emit the empty array, it unrolls it into an observable that emits nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't return an empty array, instead return an observable that emits a single sentinel value.

```js
const SENTINEL = Symbol();

of(1)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((x) => of(SENTINEL)),
    distinct(),
    mergeMap((x) => {
      if (x === SENTINEL) return fulfilled();
      // etc.
    })
  )
  .subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```